# Get bitmap from camera android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera, uri

I'm trying to open the camera from my app and get a bitmap. But this doens't work. I got this error : 
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/media/external/images/media/9969: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Here is the code :

```
 private void openCamera()
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the camera");
    image_uri =     getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);


    //Camera intent

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);




}
```

When I call openCamera(), here is the activity result :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (resultCode)
            {
                case RESULT_OK :
                {

                    //imageView.setImageURI(image_uri); this works

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    String photoPath = image_uri.toString();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //this doesnt work ! --> the bitmap is empty



                    }

                    //finish
                case RESULT_CANCELED :
                {
          //  finish();
        }
        default: {
            //finish();
        }
    }
```

I need the bitmap to store the image after that. 
It's pretty weird because the image is well saved into the gallery but I can't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would be using Glide, Picasso, or another image-loading library, and simply have it load the image from the `Uri` into your `ImageView`.

If you insist upon using your basic approach, despite its poor performance, replace:

```
String photoPath = image_uri.toString();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
```

with:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(image_uri));
```

A `Uri` is not a file.

Comment: I don't want to load it into imageView, I want to save the bitmap, the imageview.seturi(...) etc was just an example
Your code doesn't work it says  "decodefile(java.lang.string) in bitmap factory cannot be applied to java.io.inputstream"

Comment: @ImNeos: "I don't want to load it into imageView" -- your code shows you loading it into an `ImageView`. "Your code doesn't work" -- sorry, I forgot to switch methods on `BitmapFactory`. It's edited now. Use `decodeStream()`, not `decodeFile()`.